# lm function gives estimate for the y-variable also

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, coefficients

I am trying to run a simple lm model. I am using the following

```
dt <- data.table(
  y=rnorm(100,0,1),
  x1=rnorm(100,0,1),
  x2=rnorm(100,0,1),
  x3=rnorm(100,0,1))

y_var2 <- names(dt)[names(dt)%like%"y"]
x_var2 <- names(dt)[names(dt)%like%"x"]

tmp2 <- summary(a <- lm(get(y_var2)~.,dt[,c(x_var2,y_var2),with=F]))
coefs2 <- as.data.table(tmp2$coefficients,keep.rownames = T)
```

So in the end, `coefs2` should contain the estimates, p-values etc. But in the last row of the `coefs2` i also see the y-variable.

But if I use

```
tmp2 <- summary(a <- lm(y~.,dt[,c(x_var2,y_var2),with=F]))
```

Then this does not happen. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how R stores variables. y_var2 is a character "y" and you fill it into the formula as a character variable which you wish to model with all variables in your data.table dt. However, you have to tell R that you wish to evaluate the formula y~. and not "y"~. which are two different expressions for R.

```
lm( formula(paste(y_var2,"~.")),dt[,c(x_var2,y_var2),with=F])
```

will do the trick. formula constructs a formula out of the string variable with which a contructed the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it would probably be cleaner just to make the formula with `reformulate()` and the `data=` parameter of `lm`

```
tmp2 <- summary(a <- lm(reformulate(x_var2, y_var2), dt))
```